# Friedman's test in R gives different results from SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I've recently made the switch from SPSS to R for some of my data analysis. As part of this I was running some already-made analyses in R that were previously in SPSS, just to have a nice tidy script that makes sense.

My data in this case the self-ratings on feelings of Hostility of 9 participants in an isolated and confined setting. I tested them five times (Summer, Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer again). The data is non-normally distributed.

I ran the Friedman test in SPSS which gave me  `p=.012, χ2(4df)=12.79` ages ago. I re-ran the test in R today and it gave me this: `p=.951 (χ2(4df)=.69)`. This really freaks me out because it gives me reason to doubt all of my analyses so far.

Once I discovered this I re-exported the SPSS file into `.csv`, opened it with my R script and re-ran the Friedman test. To check that I wasn't accidentally using different data files. Definitely not the case.

I used the Friedman test as described by Andy Field:

```
Summer1   <- c(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  
Autumn    <- c(3,0,1,0,0,4,2,0,1)  
Winter    <- c(1,0,0,0,0,2,5,1,1) 
Spring    <- c(1,0,2,2,2,8,4,0,1)  
Summer2   <- c(3,0,2,1,0,4,7,1,1) 
Hostility <- matrix(c(Summer1, Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer2), nrow=9, byrow=TRUE) 
friedman.test(Hostility)
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this, or an idea which result is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about R results without a reproducible example.

Comment: I'll happily produce a reproducible example but how do I do that on here?

Comment: I apologise for my rookieness.

Here is the reproducible example. It gives me the values as described above (p=.951 (χ2(4df)=.69))  in RStudio Version 1.0.136.

`code` Summer1<-c(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Autumn<-c(3,0,1,0,0,4,2,0,1)
Winter<-c(1,0,0,0,0,2,5,1,1)
Spring<-c(1,0,2,2,2,8,4,0,1)
Summer2<-c(3,0,2,1,0,4,7,1,1)
Hostility<-matrix(c(Summer1, Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer2), nrow=9, byrow=TRUE)
friedman.test(Hostility)

I based this on Andy Field's description of how to run a Friedman test.

Comment: There's no need to apologize, you just need to provide that kind of information *in the body of your question*, so that people can figure out what happened. I added it to your question for you. Why not register your account (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), & take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Answer (score 4):

Always a good idea to check that your matrix actually looks like what you think it should:

```
> Hostility
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]    2    0    0    0    0
  [2,]    0    0    0    0    3
  [3,]    0    1    0    0    4
  [4,]    2    0    1    1    0
  [5,]    0    0    0    2    5
  [6,]    1    1    1    0    2
  [7,]    2    2    8    4    0
  [8,]    1    3    0    2    1
  [9,]    0    4    7    1    1
```

The problem is with `byrow=TRUE`. When constructed correctly, the Friedman test agrees with SPSS:

```
> Hostility <- matrix(c(Summer1, Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer2), nrow=length(Summer1))
> friedman.test(Hostility)

    Friedman rank sum test

data:  Hostility
Friedman chi-squared = 12.794, df = 4, p-value = 0.01233
```

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Answer (score 3):

This is a mistake in your R code.  You read the data into your matrix by rows, rather than by columns.  In the `matrix()` function call, just change the `byrow` argument to `FALSE`.  Consider:

```
...
Hostility <- matrix(c(Summer1, Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer2), nrow=9, byrow=TRUE) 
Hostility
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    2    0    0    0    0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    3
#  [3,]    0    1    0    0    4
#  [4,]    2    0    1    1    0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    2    5
#  [6,]    1    1    1    0    2
#  [7,]    2    2    8    4    0
#  [8,]    1    3    0    2    1
#  [9,]    0    4    7    1    1

Hostility2 <- matrix(c(Summer1, Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer2), nrow=9, byrow=FALSE) 
Hostility2
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    2    3    1    1    3
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#  [3,]    0    1    0    2    2
#  [4,]    0    0    0    2    1
#  [5,]    0    0    0    2    0
#  [6,]    0    4    2    8    4
#  [7,]    0    2    5    4    7
#  [8,]    0    0    1    0    1
#  [9,]    0    1    1    1    1
friedman.test(Hostility2)
#   Friedman rank sum test
# 
# data:  Hostility2
# Friedman chi-squared = 12.794, df = 4, p-value = 0.01233
```